# Google Colab: move line up / down

Tags: pycharm, google-colaboratory, keyboard-shortcuts

in PyCharm you can press `Alt+Shift+Up` or `Alt+Shift+Down` to move line up or down respectively.

(in Mac: `option+Shift+Up` or `option+Shift+Down`)

Is there such thing in Google Colab as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In google colab you can use `alt+up/down` to move the line in linux and Windows

Comment: That indeed works! also in Mac thats `⌥(option)+up/down`. not sure how I missed it and why its not in the shortcut list, perhaps its new